# Did the location for Starfleet headquarters change in Star Trek Into Darkness?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness

In the latest movie, critical executive Starfleet meetings were held in London and *not* San Francisco.  Was Starfleet HQ moved? If so, when did this happen?

Comment: When you have transporters, does it matter where you put the departments?

Comment: After *Into Darkness*, two departments of the same organization need not be on the same planet, or even the same solar system, or even the same quadrant.  Any human can just transwarp beam himself or herself to Andoria for a nice cold lunch at a moment's notice.  :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [archive / secret weapons lab](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Kelvin_Memorial_Archive) whose destruction triggered the meeting in question was in London, but the [Starfleet Headquarters](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starfleet_Headquarters) (as well as the meeting itself) was in SF.

Comment: Yes, the news media reported that the London target was non-strategic and of little importance to Starfleet (except of course for the loss of life).  It was classified information that it had in fact been a very costly target after all.